# Passing array from javascript to java servlet using Jackson

Tags: java, javascript, json, servlets, jackson

Im trying to pass an array from javascript to java servlet using Jackson, how this can be done..thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic idea should be straightforward:

Server:

```
doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
{
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  ArrayNode rootNode = mapper.readValue(req.getReader(), ArrayNode.class);
}
```

Client:

Using jQuery (you can also do it with other frameworks, or manually).  Load a copy of [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) to make sure you have JSON.stringify.

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: servletURL,
  data: JSON.stringify(jsArray),
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: 'application/json'
});
```

Comment: thanks matthew for reply...im using YUI 3, the array reach servlet and everything is ok, but i need to get the right parameter from request.
i replaced req.getReader() with req.getParameter("myArray") but still not working

Comment: nevermind...its worked i used req.getParameterValues("myArray"), thanks for helping

Comment: @Mohammed, if you're using `getParameterValues`, you're probably not using JSON.  You most likely have a regular GET query-string.

Comment: i thought its worked...im using Jackson.
so is there away to pick specific parameter from HttpServletRequest using  
ArrayNode rootNode = mapper.readValue(req.getReader(), ArrayNode.class);
??

Comment: Okay, it looks like you do need both `getParameterValues` and Jackson because of the way YUI is sending the request.

Answer (score 0):

For passing the array from the browser to the server side you don't need Jackson. You just need Ajax. For example, using jQuery you can do it this way:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'your servlet url',
  data: yourArray
});
```

Then on the server side, you might want to deserialize the JSON into a JavaBean or, in your case, a `java.util.List` using Jackson. You can do that this way:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List array = mapper.readValue(jsonText, List.class);
```

Where `jsonText` contains the String representation of `yourArray` that is sent to the server-side from the browser.

Comment: Your client code sends the data in query-string format, not JSON.