# How to pass an array of objects from javascript to Java

Tags: java, javascript, json

Hello Im trying to pass an array of objects from javascript to java , but how  can this be done..??
I've found in some posts that they do this using a hidden input. Is this the only way?
I'm a bit confused. Please tell me what do I need to do to pass my array to the server? and which javascript files and jars do I need to add?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433611/passing-array-from-javascript-to-java-servlet-using-jackson

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want a completely baked-in solution. Not sure I can provide that, but here's what I'd do.

Indeed use a hidden input field in a form, where the value of the field is a valid JSON string. Send the form to your server, and in your servlet use a JSON Java library to parse the JSON string.

Here [json-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/), [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) would do. In your case, I'd say [json-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/) would seem the easiest to use.

To generate the JSON string on the client-side, either use a framework or custom solution. For instance, [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/) has a [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function to serialize a form's fields to a JSON object directly, which you can then convert to string. Other frameworks provide similar functions.

To learn more about JSON, be sure to read the [JSON Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) and to visit the [official JSON page](http://json.org/) (which also gives you [a Java implementation of the JSON data-interchange format](http://www.json.org/java/), though maybe not the most efficient one for processing a lot of data). To make sure your generated JSON is valid, you can use [JSONLint](http://www.jsonlint.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If the objects are simple enough, you can encode your array as a JSON string. Java has libraries to encode and decode JSON.