# Converting array of Object to JSON and send it over HTTP

Tags: java, json, servlets, jackson

I have an array of object as `ArrayList` which I want to convert to JSON and send it to client over `HttpResponse` using Java and Jackson.

How I can do this?

Comment: using spring framework?

Comment: what you tried? Check http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/ after use spring....

Comment: Here I Have to write the objects first to a file. No conflict will happened if multiple users trying to access same code?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already put jackson library and using Spring framework. Mentioned following line in your spring context file.

```
<!-- Configure to plugin JSON as request and response in method handler -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        <beans:property name="messageConverters">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref bean="jsonMessageConverter" />
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
```

and Return the List/Map/Object from controller and it will internally convert it to JSON

**For Non Spring:**

```
doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
{
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  ArrayNode rootNode = mapper.readValue(req.getReader(), ArrayNode.class);
}
```

**Source:**

[Passing array from javascript to java servlet using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433611/passing-array-from-javascript-to-java-servlet-using-jackson)

http://software.danielwatrous.com/restful-java-servlet-serializing-tofrom-json-with-jackson/

Hope this helps :)

Do share your environment details if it was still not helpful and i will try to help :)

Comment: I don't have Spring framewark

Comment: i just updated my answer for non spring...servlet based scenario ..hope it helps